# How do I limit the number of cores used for a process?

Tags: c#, process, cpu-cores

I want my program to open some other processes, and one of the requirements of the project is that each process opened can only be run on a single core.

I know that a specific processor can be picked with processorAffinity but is it possible to set a maximum number of cores (in my case 1)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit number of processors used in ThreadPool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432084/limit-number-of-processors-used-in-threadpool)

Comment: I'd love to meet the person who write that requirement so i could ask him/her what on earth it is for.

Comment: @Gusdor Some old apps crash when run on multiple cores. That is why I came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try with  [ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessThreadIdealProcessor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Make sure there is an instance of notepad running.
            Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            if (notepads.Length == 0)
                Process.Start("notepad");
            ProcessThreadCollection threads;
            //Process[] notepads; 
            // Retrieve the Notepad processes.
            notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            // Get the ProcessThread collection for the first instance
            threads = notepads[0].Threads;
            // Set the properties on the first ProcessThread in the collection
            threads[0].IdealProcessor = 0;
            threads[0].ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)1;
        }
    }
}
```